# error when I export GridView to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

when I Export Grid View to Excel I have This message error
My dataBase is SQL Server and My table has 8000 rows
when i select just 1 row to gridview it export to excel without errors
but when i select all rows this problem appear 
this is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    { 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = objCalep.SelectAll(true, false, "[تاريخ الاستشهاد]");
    //    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = objCCP.CPSelectNo(2700);
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Load(reader);
    GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord drv = e.Row.DataItem as System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord;
        DataRowView dataRowView = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        DataRow drv = dataRowView.Row;

        Object ob = drv["تاريخ الاستشهاد"];
        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(ob))
        {
            DateTime dateTime = (DateTime)ob;
            e.Row.Cells[4].Text = dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            e.Row.Cells[4].Width = 100;
        }
    }
}
protected void btn_Add_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    PrepareGridViewForExport(GridView1);
    ExportGridView();
}
private void ExportGridView()
{
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=حلب.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
}

private void PrepareGridViewForExport(Control gv)
{
    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
    Literal l = new Literal();
    string name = String.Empty;
    for (int i = 0; i < gv.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        if (gv.Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(LinkButton))
        {
            l.Text = (gv.Controls[i] as LinkButton).Text;
            gv.Controls.Remove(gv.Controls[i]);
            gv.Controls.AddAt(i, l);
        }
        else if (gv.Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(DropDownList))
        {
            l.Text = (gv.Controls[i] as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text;
            gv.Controls.Remove(gv.Controls[i]);
            gv.Controls.AddAt(i, l);
        }
        else if (gv.Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(CheckBox))
        {
            l.Text = (gv.Controls[i] as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False";
            gv.Controls.Remove(gv.Controls[i]);
            gv.Controls.AddAt(i, l);
        }
        if (gv.Controls[i].HasControls())
        {
            PrepareGridViewForExport(gv.Controls[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is image error [Error message](http://im37.gulfup.com/Lpu13.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I can't read much of that error message, but I'm guessing that the ViewState data for the grid is larger than the maximum request length configured on your site (I believe the default is 4MB).

Try changing `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="158334976" />` in the `<system.web>` section of your web.config.

If that works, you could leave the maxRequestLength at a high enough value, or disable ViewState for your grid, though you'd have to retrieve the data from the database again after the postback.